# processlist showing '%' as host from trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger, insert

I'm trying to populate a certain column in a table with the host/IP of the caller. I have an insert trigger on the table which sets the column like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER access_insert_trg BEFORE INSERT ON access
FOR EACH ROW 
set NEW.hostname = (select SUBSTRING_INDEX(host,':',1)
                    from information_schema.processlist 
                    WHERE ID=connection_id())
;
```

I end up getting `%` as the hostname even though when I manually run the same query on the `processlist` table I get an actual hostname. I've checked the `connection_id()` value and it's correctly the id of a row in `processlist` with a real `hostname:port` value in the host column.

I can't figure out how or why it's being translated to a generic `%:<port>` value. Any ideas on what's going on & how to fix it?

I'm using MySQL 5.1.57 if that changes anything.

Comment: I know little about MySQL, but I guess it'll be the host permission '%' that allowed the connection

Comment: It seemed likely initially that it could be a permissions problem, but in my test I logged in as the same user that is inserting into the table & the identical query found in the trigger returns a valid hostname (Not '%') so it seems like that user has the right access. - stumped -

Comment: From the same host though? I'm thinking it's the permissions match you're seeing

Comment: Good thought. But ya, even on the same host.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you doing the insert that fires the trigger from inside a stored procedure?

Apparently, when inside a stored procedure, the row matching your thread in information_schema.processlist is populated (albeit somewhat half-heartedly) with the DEFINER username and hostname if the calling user is not the same as the definer.

This is somewhat unexpected, so I'll document it a bit more, below...

But first, your fix:

```
SET NEW.hostname = SUBSTRING_INDEX(user(),'@',-1);
```

If this works, it's definitely a better approach -- it's a much more lightweight way to get the information you're looking for, and seems to return the correct answer where the other doesn't.  Making the call to information_schema.processlist is expensive, since apparently [the entire table is rendered](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/processlist-table.html) each time you call for it.

---

Now, to replicate the behavior for the benefit of those who (me included) whouldn't have believed it without seeing it in action:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `bizarre` $$
CREATE DEFINER=`super_dev`@`%` PROCEDURE `bizarre`()
BEGIN

SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE Id = CONNECTION_ID();

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Now to test the SP.  Note that I am *not* connecting as super_dev, I am connecting as a different super user.  If I connect as super_dev (the DEFINER user), this works the way we expect.

```
mysql> call bizarre();
+-------+---------------+---------+------------+---------+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID    | USER          | HOST    | DB         | COMMAND | TIME | STATE     | INFO                                                                    |
+-------+---------------+---------+------------+---------+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 17261 | super_dev     | %:49730 | dev_testsv | Query   |    0 | executing | SELECT * FROM information_schema.processlist WHERE Id = CONNECTION_ID() |
+-------+---------------+---------+------------+---------+------+-----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

My best guess, this is an artifact of the environment changes that need to happen internally when a stored procedure is called.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense and the fix to use user() instead of the processlist works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: +1 We occasionally experience performance issues on MySQL and we use the "show full processlist" command to see which connections and statements are active while they are going on. When we saw our privileged deployment user executing code we spent a whole morning trying to work out what was going on. It was showing '%' (percent) as the host name, and then a valid port. We even disabled the deployment user, and still it seemed to be connecting and running code. Thought it was a bug until this post. Trying to think of any more keywords I can add to this comment to help others find it :-)